# Is it possible to get rid of the search button (magnifying glass) from the bottom bar?

Tags: amazon, kindle-fire

The Kindle Fire has a feature through which you can search your collections or the web at the touch of a button.  This component can be accessed from the bottom bar, where the <kbd>home</kbd>, <kbd>back</kbd>, and <kbd>favorite</kbd> buttons are.

While it sounds like a nice feature, it's easy to bump in passing.  I would like to eliminate this possibility.  Is there a way to get rid of the search icon within the settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overflow menu is automatic and controlled by the OS (similar to the Action menu on devices based on the default Android experience). You can partly hide the whole Content Bar by making your app full screen but you can't hide it completely as it replaces the functionality of the home & back buttons on non-kindle android devices.

According to [the Kindle Fire User Guide](http://kindle.s3.amazonaws.com/Kindle_Fire_Users_Guide.pdf) (on page 8, section “Content Bar“), the search button helps users search their content library, not search within the current app. Therefore, the search icon is fixed and it will take you to the platform search… unless you override it [as described here](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/soft-key-bar.html) (scroll to bottom).